# Remove associated entity after clearing related form fields

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have `Company` entity with `One-To-One` relationship with `Manager` entity. For editing I use Form Component.
When I clear all the Manager's fields on a form - the related DB fields also cleared (but the row itself remains), what is not a desirable behaviour. In that case the row must be deleted from DB.
How can it be achieved?

Comment: That behaviour is normal, you are just deleting the values of the columns for that row... Just create a delete button?

Comment: I thought that there is some Form option for removing such a rows. A delete button is too much work I think =) It's not a collection, Manager entity renders as an inline form with two fields - delete button should delete this form from the main form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This IS the desirable behaviour, since Doctrine is an Object-Relational Mapper. If the `Manager` still exists in your model with all fields `null` it will be saved as a table row with an `id` and all other field `null`.

That said you can achive your behaviour easily in you business logic. A simple approach is to allow:

```
public function setManager(Manager $manager = null) {
    $this->manager = $manager;
}
```

Note that the important part is not the setter method itself, but the fact that you set to null `$this->manager` property. Then in you controller action do:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    if (<all properties are null>) {
        $entityManager->remove($company->getManager());
        $company->setManager(null);
    }
    // your other logic here
    $entityManager->persist($company);
    $entityManager->flush();
}
```

Of course, this will put some logic to the controller and is not the cleanest method, but is a good start. When you get confidence with Doctrine, you can refactor the cascade deletion and the `setManager(null)` in a EventListener bound to `onFlush` event. See the [official doc](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush) for this.

Comment: Thanks, truth be told I hoped there is some setting for such a deletion, kinda `delete_if_empty`, because didn't want to put extra logic in a controller or a listener, since the less code you have the clearer it is =)

Comment: @basil In recent version of doctrine (especially 2.5) you have orphan-removal feature, which will avoid the need of calling remove method on the entityManager. But still, the entity "manager" instance need to be unset from the "company" instance.

Comment: In fact the Manager assosiation of the Company entity already has `orphanRemoval=true`. This option also removes Manager assosiation when Company itself are removed. It also somehow can help to delete Manger in case of when all the fields are empty?

Comment: no, it does "just" that. It's very useful for "own-a" associations, when removing an association equals to removing the entity.